# Google maps https on localhost issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use google maps javascript API but in chrome's console I am getting the following error:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://localhost:8000". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

I already changed my local server to run in https, what else do I have to do?

Comment: You're clearly getting a same-origin error? Why `google.com` would try to access `localhost` isn't really clear though, but it can't.

Comment: But several systems use google maps api, there must be a way to get rid of it

Comment: Can you create a code sample that demonstrates this?